# Zoom image without scaling overlay annotations (CALayers)

Tags: ios, user-interface, calayer

I'm implementing a view with an image that I can zoom, pan and rotate and where I can add some annotations (**lines**) using `CALayers`. My doubt is how can I perform zoom operations on the underlaying image only and keep the annotations size and position? with my first experiment I ended up with all the annotation lines zoomed too... is there a good library out there to handle this kind of needs? or which is in your opinion the best way to create something like this?

This is what I have in mind:

**1)** The main structure is based on two sibling views (Image and Annotations)

**2)** When I apply zoom I apply it to Image only.

**3)** I keep track of all the rotations and scaling operations and I apply a transform matrix to the points that define the lines in the annotations view, so the point will just be drawn at the new positions keeping line width unscaled.

To me it sounds a little bit overcomplicated solution... there should be something easier :/

Comment: Do you only need the `CALayers` to sit statically on top of the image view as it moves around and scales?

Comment: Exactly but CALayers lines has to keep same width and position in relation to underneath image rotation and scale changes.